# React Follow Function activates on page load

Tags: reactjs, rails-api

I am trying to implement a follow/unfollow function in a react rails-api web application. Currently the follow and unfollow post/delete just fine when I click the follow/unfollow button.

However, whenever a user visits another users page it will follow/unfollow when the page loads without clicking the follow/unfollow button. I do not understand why this is happening since I have, for my post/delete, the useEffect second param set to go off when the state for my follow/unfollow changes.

Please help me figure out why this is happening and how to prevent this. Let me know if more information is needed.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import {Link, useParams} from 'react-router-dom'
import decode from 'jwt-decode'
function NotUserPage() {
    const {id} = useParams()
    const [user, setUser] = useState({})
    const loggedUser = decode(localStorage.getItem("token"))
    const username = loggedUser.username
    const userId = loggedUser.user_id 
    const [followUnFollow, setFollowUnFollow] = useState("true")
   
  
    const toggleFollowUnFollow = () => {
        setFollowUnFollow(!followUnFollow)
    }
    

    const fetchUserData = () => {
        fetch(`http://localhost:3000/users/${id}`)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => setUser(data))
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchUserData()
    }, [])


    const unFollow = () => {
        fetch(`http://localhost:3000/users/${id}/unfollow`, {
            method: "POST",
            body:  JSON.stringify({
                follower_id: userId,
                followee_id: id
            }),
            headers: {
                "Content-type": "application/json",
                "Authorization": `bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`,
              },
            
            })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => console.log(data))
                
    }
  
    useEffect(() => {
        unFollow()
    }, [followUnFollow])
   

 


    const handleFollow = () => {
        fetch(`http://localhost:3000/users/${id}/follow`, {
            method: "POST",
            body:  JSON.stringify({
                follower_id: userId,
                followee_id: id
            }),
            headers: {
                "Content-type": "application/json",
                "Authorization": `bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`,
              },
            
            })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => console.log(data))
                
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        handleFollow()
    }, [followUnFollow])
  
    const fButton = () => {
       
        toggleFollowUnFollow() ? handleFollow() : unFollow()

    }

    return (
        <div>
           {user.username} 
           <button onClick={fButton}>follow</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default NotUserPage
```

Comment: On component load useEffect is always run regardless of dependencies. To prevent that, put an if statement on the first line of useEffect, useEffect will run but will short-circuit/quit early if condition is not met

Comment: Thanks @Aleks. It is working as intended now. My understanding is that with the if statement, it is now functioning properly as a ComponentDidUpdate?

Comment: depending on if statement, if you block first render like this `let k=0 if(k===0){k++;return;}` inside useEffect then yes. In your case I would just set followUnFollow default value to undefined and check for it in if statement.

Comment: Also you really don't need both hooks, I will add edited code as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import {Link, useParams} from 'react-router-dom'
import decode from 'jwt-decode'
function NotUserPage() {
    const {id} = useParams()
    const [user, setUser] = useState({})
    const loggedUser = decode(localStorage.getItem("token"))
    const username = loggedUser.username
    const userId = loggedUser.user_id 
    const [following, setFollowing] = useState(false)
  
    const fetchUserData = () => {
        fetch(`http://localhost:3000/users/${id}`)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => setUser(data))
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchUserData()
    }, [])

    const unFollow = () => {
        fetch(`http://localhost:3000/users/${id}/unfollow`, {
            method: "POST",
            body:  JSON.stringify({
                follower_id: userId,
                followee_id: id
            }),
            headers: {
                "Content-type": "application/json",
                "Authorization": `bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`,
              },
            
            })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => console.log(data))
            .then(() => setFollowing(false))
                
    }
 
    const handleFollow = () => {
        fetch(`http://localhost:3000/users/${id}/follow`, {
            method: "POST",
            body:  JSON.stringify({
                follower_id: userId,
                followee_id: id
            }),
            headers: {
                "Content-type": "application/json",
                "Authorization": `bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`,
              },
            
            })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => console.log(data))
            .then(() => setFollowing(true))
                
    }
  
    const fButton = () => following ? unFollow() : handleFollow();


    return (
        <div>
           {user.username} 
           <button onClick={fButton}>follow</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default NotUserPage
```

Comment: Thank you for your help  @Aleks. When I try to code snippet and click on my follow button it will set state to false and not alternate between true/false. I tried using a single useEffect with an if statement to determine if follow or unFollow would run and I got the same result. Please advise if possible.

Comment: change this `const fButton = () => following ? handleFollow() : unFollow();` to `const fButton = () => following ? unFollow() : handleFollow() ;`

Comment: It is working as intended except on page refresh the state is reset :(

Comment: That's how hooks work. They don't persist any data. You need to fetch required user data on app load and persist it in global state. An object containing people that user follows, could be one of those things. So `const [following, setFollowing] = useState(false)` won't be just false, it would be whatever it is according to your remote datastore.

Comment: Oh man! You are right...Everything is working great thanks to your guidance!